# curl append "Resource id #2" to the output

Tags: php, curl

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/api/11122233A");
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $curl;
```

The API returns a JSON when I manually visit the URL, however with curl the output is like `{json things}Resource id #2`. Why?

I'm reading a couple of similar questions, but mine is different because I'm actually getting the data, not just a `Resource id #2`message.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 check what? the response? it's the same, the JSON + `Resource id #2`

Comment: @m02ph3u5 no let me clarify. If I call "`http://localhost/api/11122233A`, the output is ok. Now if I call a newly created file which will be the front-end that uses the API (`localhost/api/index.php`) the result is the JSON + the `resource id # 2`. `index.php` only have the above code so far.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 then why calling curl from the CLI does return the JSON and anything else?

Comment: what are you doing on the command line? `$ curl ...` or `php -f index.php`?

Comment: `curl --url 'http://localhost/api/11122233A'`

Comment: Well that's something different. In your question you're calling curl from your php script that outputs a resource (instead of the response). With `curl ...` you're calling curl directly and get back the response - no php and resource involved there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curl_init()` returns a `resource` (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php)

Hence `echo $curl;` or `echo curl_init();` will give you something like `Resource id #2`.

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/api/11122233A");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);   
echo $output;
```

For further details see http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

---

As you're saying curl works for you via the command line (i. e. `$ curl ...`) there's a workaround for you. Just [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) you curl command.

Example:

```
$output = exec('curl http://localhost/api/11122233A');
echo $output;
```

Comment: actually I tried that before posting here, and if I use the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER I only get the `Resource id #2` and not the JSON.

Comment: Really? You should double-check that. It'd be a weird thing. Assuming you're not accidentially messing things up and it works for you using curl directly you can just call curl via `exec()`, `system()` or `passthru()`.

Comment: The difference between `echo $curl` and `echo curl_exec($curl)` is than instead of having the `Resource id # 2`appended to the JSON, I have a `1` appended to it, because that's the output of curl_exec() as you can see in the docs.

Comment: The docs say that `curl_exec()` outputs `Resource id # 1`? No they don't. Maybe I misunderstood. Please try again.